# Use Picasso in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, picasso

I need help with connecting picasso to listview, do not know how to do this, picasso connected and it works, but the fact that one was already in another problem.
The list must be of a picture, and then all that has been done (checkbox and text). Due to the fact that I'm a novice, I do not know what to do for it. I will be glad if you could help me with this! 
Thank you in advance!

listview part

```
    final String[] productnames = {
            "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3" };
    selection = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.aboutform);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productlist);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, productnames);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selection.setText("");
            SparseBooleanArray chosen = ((ListView) parent).getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < chosen.size(); i++) {
                if (chosen.valueAt(i)) {
                    selection.append(productnames [chosen.keyAt(i)] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Picasso.with(ctx).load(imgPath).fit().into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

Comment: I know how to use picasso separately, but I need to insert it inside, so you can just like to add a few strings and they are to be displayed

Comment: follow these link....

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Answer (score 1):

You can use url instead of drawable image in load

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load("https://s3om/foodev/hotel/" + imageLocation).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_hotel).error(R.drawable.ic_default_hotel).into(holder.imageviewHotel);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) of custom listview

hope it will help you